# Validate a number with grouped thousands with decimal to the hundreth

Tags: php, validation, number-formatting

Looking for a simple way (Function/RegEx) to validate a number with grouped thousands.

Example Numbers:

```
.00 - 999.00 should validate
1,000.00 should validate
100,000.00 etc... should validate
100,000,000,000,000.00 should validate
```

Now I've seen the [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), but this formats the number not validates.

I wanted to use a RegEx but lost on how to do so.

```
preg_match(/^[\d]\,?\.[\d]{2}$/, $number);
```

but this doesn't work.

I've also looked at the [money_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) but again this is format and not validation.

Comment: Which things shouldn't validate, 1,000? 1,000.000?

Comment: Is the user who have to submit these numbers ?

Comment: 1,000.000 should NOT validate as the decimal is showing the thousandths number

Comment: yes the user will be entering these numbers

Comment: So why don't let them submit simple numbers?

Comment: how do you know the user doesnt mean one thousand with three decimal precision when entering 1,000.000?

Comment: The input needs to be valid US Currency format, The input must be exact with no errors before submission. If it was just a simple number formatting issue I would use the money_format()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)?\.\d{2}$
```

Comment: What does the colon in this pattern do?

Comment: Thanks, just one question. I know the ? makes the character optional but what does this do to the expression :

Comment: @Ben, @Phill: Do you mean the `?:` parts? They just mean that the parenthesised group is non-capturing. Using non-capturing groups supposedly gives a (very small) performance improvement when you don't actually need to capture the text. http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the insight and the RegEx

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head:

```
preg_match('%^[\d,]*\.\d{2}$%', $number);
```

This will match all of the numbers you mentioned (in fact: every string which starts with a combination of digits and commas and ends on "." and to digits).

Again, this is untested but should work.

Comment: This will allow 1000.00 which should be in this format: 1,000.00

Comment: This will also allow: 1,0,0.00

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a PHP5.3+ you could try the Intl number formatter:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php

Comment: Thanks I am running 5.x but it's not a formatting issue but a validation issue. Thanks for the effort